# Laravel 4 , PHP - Disable form checkbox

Tags: php, forms, laravel

Is it possible to do this, and how? I have checkboxes which are either ticked or unticked and they need to be disabled. I have tried the following with no luck

// ticked

```
Form::checkbox(
    $formOption['data']->ant_answer_type_id, 
    $formOption['data']->ant_answer_title, 
    true,
    array('disabled')
)
```

// unticked

```
Form::checkbox(
   $formOption['data']->ant_answer_type_id, 
   $formOption['data']->ant_answer_title, 
   array('disabled')
)
```

Comment: i am new to laravel, but have you tried jquery disabling??

Comment: There is no difference between those 2 code snippets!

Comment: @Marcin your answer is the correct one and for the live of me I don't know why my code snippet wasn't working. Unfortunatly while it did disable  the checkboxes it didnt produce the desired results (The result I wanted was that they were disabled but still displayed previous input). I have since found the solution with the desired result and will post the answer late today.

Answer (score 3):

In both codes above you set `true` so both of them are checked.

When you use:

```
{{ Form::checkbox(
    'test',
    1,
    true,
    array('disabled')
)
}}

{{ Form::checkbox(
    'test2',
    2,
    false,
    array('disabled')
)
}}
```

you will get 2 disabled checkboxes, first checked, second unchecked